# What methodology is being used to poll SQL instances when using sqlcmd with the -L switch?

Tags: sql-server, network, sqlcmd

I've discovered that issuing `sqlcmd -L` from the console of a SQL host in my network only reveals other instances on the same subnet. It used to reveal all instances on the network so I was wondering if an O/S or network firewall rule is blocking polling attempts outside the subnet. What firewall rule can I asked my network engineers to establish to allow polling for instances beyond the immediate subnet?

Comment: To help answer the question about what methodology is being used.... one observation we've made is that it is definitely not just polling live servers. When we run sqlcmd -L, we get 7 results from servers that definitely don't exist anymore.  They have SPN's in Active Directory however, so we have a suspicion sqlcmd is somehow querying AD as well as sending out a broadcast message to look for live servers.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server discovery is attempted using UDP port 1434.

You'd need to get UDP traffic destined for 255.255.255.255 on port 1434 opened in your local router to see servers from other subnets.

See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2057/why-listing-all-of-your-sql-servers-does-not-always-work/ for more info.